# htaccess hide extension for subdomain located in subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am currently building a website and have created a dev environment in a subdomain.

**Live Env:** foobar.com

**Live Dir:** /public_html

**Dev Env:** dev.foobar.com

**Dev Dir:** /public_html/dev

While this isn't the most ideal setup, its the best I can do on a tight budget. I found a simple htaccess tutorial that allowed me to remove the index part of the url and hide the file extension which works well in my live environment:

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/foobar/public_html/php.ini
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Unfortunately this still points to the live php.ini file when I access my dev environment (I have a separate php.ini file in the dev subdirectory), so I decided to make a copy of the htaccess file that would point to dev and drop it in the dev subfolder.  This causes my dev environment to stop functioning though (just white screens across the board), so I'm guessing it has to do with the rewrite code.  The problem is that I am **atrocious** with figuring out the syntax.

Is it as easy as adding in a "dev." somewhere or could I possibly even reference my dev php.ini file in some other way?

Comment: Can you isolate the problem by commenting out (i) PHPRC line (ii) rewrite lines?

Comment: The problem goes away when the PHPRC line is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the ini file, just create another htaccess file and add it to the dev directory:

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/foobar/public_html/dev/php.ini
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Though, I have no idea how this is getting rid of the `www`, there's no rule that looks at the hostname or redirects.

Comment: Sorry, I meant hides the index part of the url.  I will edit the OP.